# how to setPayloadXML contains json string

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

now I want to setPayloadXML using script mediator,
but the xml payload contains a json string like this:

```
mc.setPayloadXML(<ruleDetail>{"asdf":"asdfsdf"}</ruleDetail>);
```

It goes wrong, because I found in the documentation:

```
var symbol = mc.getPayloadXML()..*::Code.toString();
mc.setPayloadXML(
m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples/xsd">
<m:request>
  <m:symbol>{symbol}</m:symbol>
</m:request>
</m:getQuote>);
```

so the `{}` symbol seems like a placeholder, but how can do if the content of the node is a json string